# Microsoft BizTalk interface system relationship

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

We have used Microsoft BizTalk 2006 to perform as a data hub for several interfaced system's information exchange.

Inside BizTalk, we use Receive Port, Receive Location, Flat-File Disassembler, Xml-Mapping, Send Port Group Filtering, Orchestration, Dynamic Send Port to determine the message flow.

Is there any idea on how to extract the information from BizTalk such that Admin can know what are the relationship between those interfaced systems (e.g. system A transfer budgetting data to system B etc)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any automated tool that can produce the documentation which demonstrates the relationship between interfaced systems as there just simply isn't enough metadata built into the product. However http://biztalk2010autodc.codeplex.com/ and http://biztalkdocumenter.codeplex.com/ are two good places to start at automating the documentation generation process.

I have seen the sort of documentation you are looking for in the past produced in Visio which provides an easy to understand overview of the various message routes/relationships etc.